# Returning an array from a method

Tags: java, arrays, swing, methods

THis is in the main class

```
actionsClass actionObject = new actionsClass(tipArray, hourArray, 
     hourlyWageInput, gasArray, wageArray, incomeArray, totalHourlyEarnings, 
     totalGas, totalHours, avgGasLabel);

actionObject.calculateTable();
```

This is my class where I am trying to implement the method (there are currently excessive declared variables):

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class actionsClass {

private JLabel hourlyWage, blank, row2, totalTips, totalHours, totalHourlyEarnings, 
totalPay, weekPay, day, totalGas, totalHoursLabel, totalTipsLabel, totalGasLabel, 
totalWageLabel, avgGas, avgGasLabel;
private JTextField hourlyWageInput;

private double incomeArray[] = new double[7];
private JTextField tipArray[] = new JTextField[7];
private JTextField hourArray[] = new JTextField[7];
private JTextField gasArray[]= new JTextField[7];
private JLabel wageArray[] =new JLabel[7];


public actionsClass() {
}

public actionsClass(JTextField[] tipArray, JTextField[] hourArray,
        JTextField hourlyWageInput, JTextField[] gasArray,
        JLabel[] wageArray, double[] incomeArray,
        JLabel totalHourlyEarnings, JLabel totalGas, JLabel totalHours,
        JLabel avgGasLabel) {
    this.tipArray = tipArray;
    this.hourArray = hourArray;
    this.hourlyWageInput = hourlyWageInput;
    this.gasArray = gasArray;
    this.wageArray =  wageArray;
    this.incomeArray =  incomeArray;
    this.totalHourlyEarnings =  totalHourlyEarnings;
    this.totalGas = totalGas;
    this.totalHours = totalHours;
    this.avgGasLabel = avgGasLabel;
}

public String calculateTable (){
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        double tipx = Double.parseDouble(tipArray[i].getText());
        double houry = Double.parseDouble(hourArray[i].getText());
        double hourlyz = Double.parseDouble(hourlyWageInput.getText());

        String[] wageArrayStrings = null;

        if (houry != 0 ){
            wageArrayStrings[i] = String.format("%.2f", (hourlyz*houry+tipx)/houry);

        }
        else {
            wageArrayStrings[i] = ("$ 0.00");
        }

    }
    return wageArrayStrings[];
}
```

}

There is a syntax error on return wageArrayStrings[]; with or without brackets. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the  return type should be `String[]`.

Then you need to initialize the array (as @MattBall points out, before the loop):

```
String[] wageArrayStrings = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
```

Then you can do

```
return wageArrayStrings;
```

Comment: N.B. the array should be declared & initialized outside of the loop.

Comment: this was my primary issue it appears. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

It should be just return `wageArrayStrings`; no need of square brackets and return type should be `String[]` instead `String` (assuming your intention is returning String array).

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be (changed function returned type too) -

```
public String[] calculateTable () {

    //// your code.
    return wageArrayStrings;
}
```

Also, you have not initialized your array. You should do that before the for loop.